# When $f(t)=ab(1-e^{-t})-c(e-e^{-t})>0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Consider the function $f(t)=ab(1-e^{-t})-c(e-e^{-t})$, for $t>0$, where $a,b,c>0$.
 Can we find a sufficient condition on $a,b,c$ such that $f(t)>0$ for all $t>0$ ?

Comment: It's impossible to make it positive for all $t > 0$ since $f(0) = -c(e-1) < 0$ unless $c \leq 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\forall t>0,\,f'(t)=(ab-c)e^{-t}$

If $ab\ge c$ then $\forall t>0,\,f'(t)\ge 0$ and so $f$ is an increasing function. $f$ is also continuous at $0$ and so:

$\forall t>0,\,f(t)\ge \lim\limits_{t\to 0^+}f(t)=f(0)=-c(e-1)$

While $e>1$ and $c>0$ so f(0)<0. That's no good.

If $ab<c$ then $\forall t>0,\,f'(t)<0$ and so $f$ is a strictly decreasing function. $f$ is also continuous at $0$ and so:

$\forall t>0,\,f(t)< \lim\limits_{t\to 0^+}f(t)=f(0)=-c(e-1)<0$

And so we can't find $a,b,c>0$ such as $\forall t>0,\, f(t)>0$

Comment: But one of the conditions is $c>0$.

Comment: oh yes I didn't pay attention

Comment: I just released that this is equivalent to $\dfrac{e-e^{-t}}{1-e^{-t}}<\dfrac{ab}{c}$ but $\dfrac{e-e^{-t}}{1-e^{-t}}$ cannot be bounded because of singularity in $0$.

Comment: That's an easier proof!